# Why is there a suggested edits review queue for Meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, review-queues

When I clicked review on the top of [meta.judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/), I noticed that exists a [Suggested Edits Review queue](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits).
This makes no sense, because (IIRC) users with <2K rep can't suggest edits on Meta, and users with >2K rep have their edits applied automatically.

I don't think that this queue goes back to the main site, because the other queues under [meta.judaism/review](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/review) don't match up with those on the main site -- First Posts and Late Answers are missing, and the recent reviewers are different for Close and Reopen votes (on Meta, apparently just Double AA and msh210).

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggested edits on tag wikis get queued for <20k users. Try it :)

Comment: Main site tag wikis or Meta tag wikis? ....and if they're cued for all users <20K, then shouldn't they be reviewed by users >20K?

Comment: @Shokhet Meta-tag wikis. At least, I think so. Please try! They are reviewed by >5k I think (and it's smart enough to not give you your own suggestion to review).

Comment: "*This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed*" ....though not [linkified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240301/266359).....oh. I didn't see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240375/266359).....

Comment: @Shokhet [Approved.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31)

Comment: All right; I guess that's that, then. Thanks for clarifiying!

Comment: @Shokhet Incidentally: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

Comment: Hm....I think I'll work on [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) first, though....would want to do that more often than edit tag wikis without having them approved, I think.